# Prove $\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{3b^2+2c^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}+\frac{3c^2+2a^2}{c(c^2+a^2)}\ge\frac{15}{2}$ for $abc=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Prove that: $$\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{3b^2+2c^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}+\frac{3c^2+2a^2}{c(c^2+a^2)}\ge\frac{15}{2}.$$

I tried to use AM-GM as $$\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{3b^2+2c^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}+\frac{3c^2+2a^2}{c(c^2+a^2)}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}\cdot\frac{3b^2+2c^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}\cdot\frac{3c^2+2a^2}{c(c^2+a^2)}}\ge\frac{15}{2}$$
Thus, it remains to prove $$8(3a^2+2b^2)(3b^2+2c^2)(3c^2+2a^2)\ge 125(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)$$
From here, I am confusing whether this statement is true or not.

Could you please give me some hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Sketch of a proof.*

The desired inequality is written as
$$\frac{2}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + \frac{2}{c}
+ \frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} + \frac{b}{b^2 + c^2} + \frac{c}{c^2+a^2} \ge \frac{15}{2}. \tag{1}$$

By AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + \frac{2}{c}
+ 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} \cdot \frac{b}{b^2 + c^2} \cdot \frac{c}{c^2+a^2}} \ge \frac{15}{2}.\tag{2}$$

Using $a^2 + b^2 \ge \frac12(a + b)^2$, we have
$$\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2} - \frac{1}{\frac12(a + b)^2}
= - \frac{(a - b)^2}{(a^2+b^2)(a+b)^2}
\ge - \frac{(a - b)^2}{\frac12(a+b)^2(a+b)^2}$$
which results in
$$\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2} \ge \frac{1}{\frac12(a + b)^2}
- \frac{(a - b)^2}{\frac12(a+b)^2(a+b)^2} = \frac{8ab}{(a + b)^4}. \tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2}{a} + \frac{2}{b} + \frac{2}{c}
+ 3\sqrt[3]{abc \cdot \frac{8ab\cdot 8bc\cdot 8ca}{(a + b)^4(b+c)^4(c+a)^4}} \ge \frac{15}{2}.\tag{4}$$

We use the pqr method. Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc = 1$. (4) is written as
$$2q + 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{512}{(pq - 1)^4}} \ge \frac{15}{2}. \tag{5}$$

Using the known inequality
$2q^3 + 9r^2 \ge 7pqr$, we have $pq\le \frac{2q^3 + 9}{7}$. It suffices to prove that
$$2q + 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{512}{(\frac{2q^3 + 9}{7} - 1)^4}} \ge \frac{15}{2} \tag{6}$$
which is true for all $q \ge 3$.

Answer (score 0):

I started off in the same way, but have a simpler proof.

Let $c$ be smallest and $a = Kc \ge b = Lc \ge c$.

When $K = L = 1$ the theorem is proved.

Thus $a = Kc \ge b = Lc > c$, and $c \le 1$.

We have, $KLc^3= 1$.

We will show that the least upper bound occurs when $K = 1$. But then $c = 1$ so L having been held fixed, $L = 1$.

We have to prove,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{a}{a^2 + b^2} + \frac{2}{a} + \text{cyclic permutations} \geq \frac{15}{2} \\
&\frac{1}{Kc(1 + \frac{L^2}{K^2})} + \frac{2}{Kc} + \text{terms with } b + \text{terms with } c \geq \frac{15}{2} \\
&\text{Then} \\
&\frac{1}{(KL)^{1/3}}\left[\frac{1}{K}\left(2 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{L^2}{K^2}}\right)\right] + \frac{1}{(KL)^{1/3}}\left[\frac{1}{L}\left(2 + \frac{1}{L + \frac{1}{L}}\right)\right] + \frac{1}{(KL)^{1/3}}\left[2 + \frac{1}{1 + K^2}\right] \\
&\text{has least upper bound of } K = 1.
\end{align*}